# Is there any solution to end an endless loop function?

Tags: javascript

Is there any solution to escape from the endless function, code like this:

```
var endless = function(){
   while(true){};
}

killWhenTimout(endless, 5000);
```

I am looking for a solution like killWhenTimeout, killWhenTimeout will kill the loop if time is out.
Any suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: Without a flag in the conditional that can get set in the timeout function? I really don't think so

Comment: No, not in JavaScript, unless it's part of the loop itself. Why do you want this in the first place? Where's the benefit in freezing the browser for 5 seconds?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, `killWhenTimout` just won't get a chance to be executed.

Comment: @cookiemonster, set 5 seconds, means give up if can not figure out in 5 seconds, otherwise the browser will freezing forever.

Answer (score 1):

If `endless` function doesn't require any special API, for example manipulating DOM, you could run it within a WebWorker. And then terminate it after the timeout, if it is still running.

Take a look at this article for details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers.